MySQL Pool Long-polling ETIMEDOUT and PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST (Node.js)
I am developing software that runs 24/7 on PM2, performing long-polling by querying the database with SELECT statements every second (I also tried querying every 20 seconds, but that didn’t solve the issue). It frequently performs batch INSERT operations, but I am unable to resolve connection timeouts (ETIMEDOUT) and connection loss (PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST).
import mysql from 'mysql2/promise';
import { config } from 'dotenv';
import { images } from './images.js';
import { labels } from './labels.js';
import { nodes } from './nodes.js';
import { runs } from './runs.js';
import { products } from './products.js';
import { utils } from '../utils/_controller.js';
import { queue } from './queue.js';
config();

let pool;

const logger = utils.createDebugLogger('MySQL');

/** 
 * Executes a query on the database
 * @param {string} query - The query to execute
 * @param {Array} params - The parameters to pass to the query
 * @returns {Promise<[mysql.QueryResult, mysql.FieldPacket[]]>} - The result of the query
*/

const _execute = async (query, params, errorDelay, attempts) => {
    if (attempts >= 5) {
        logger.error(`Error while performing query: ${e.message}`, null, e);
        throw new Error('Failed to execute query after 5 attempts');
    }

    let connection;
    const pool = await getInstance();

    try {
        connection = await pool.getConnection();
        return await connection.query(query, params);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);

        const timedOut = e.code == "ETIMEDOUT" || e.code == "PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST";

        logger.error(`Error while performing query: ${e.message}${timedOut ? ", retrying..." : ''}`, null, e);

        if (timedOut) {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, errorDelay)); // Wait 30 seconds to restore the connection
            return _execute(query, params, attempts + 1);
        }
    } finally {
        if (connection) {
            try {
                connection.release();
            } catch (releaseError) {
                logger.error(`Error while releasing connection: ${releaseError.message}`, null, releaseError);
            }
        }
    }
}

const execute = async (query, params) => {
    return await _execute(query, params, 30000, 0);
};


/**
 * Gets the database connection instance
 * @returns {Promise<mysql.Pool>}
 */
const getInstance = async () => {
    if (pool) return pool;

    try {
        pool = mysql.createPool({
            host: process.env.DB_HOST,
            user: process.env.DB_USER,
            password: process.env.DB_PASS || "",
            database: process.env.DB_NAME,
            waitForConnections: true,
            connectionLimit: 10,
            queueLimit: 0,
            idleTimeout: 10000,
        });

        logger.success('Created MySQL pool');
    } catch (e) {
        logger.error(`Error while creating MySQL pool: ${e.message}`, null, e);
    }

    return pool;
}


export const db = {
    execute,
    getInstance,
    logger,

    nodes,
    images,
    labels,
    runs,
    queue,
    products
};

I tried to add delays between queries and made it capable of attempting multiple times to prevent the connection to timeout, but I still achieved nothing.

Please provide the SQL for the "long-running" query you perform every second (or every 20 seconds).  Also SHOW CREATE TABLE for the table.
